The last vector in the basis of $ \mathrm T_pM $ induced by a boundary chart at a boundary point $ p $ of a manifold with boundary is special
Let $ M $ be a smooth manifold with boundary of dimension $ n > 1 $. In this question this will mean that $ M $ is locally modeled on the half space $ \mathbb H^n = \{x^n\geqq 0\}\subset \mathbb R^n $.
Let $ p\in \partial M $, and pick a coordinate chart $ (U,\phi) $ around $ p $. One can show that $ (U,\phi) $ induces a basis $ \{\partial_1\rvert_p,\dots,\partial_n\rvert_p\} $ of the tangent space $ \mathrm T_pM $, where
$$
\partial_\mu f = \frac{\partial(f\circ \phi^{-1})}{\partial x^\mu}(\phi(p))
$$
if $ \mu = 1,\dots,n - 1 $ and
$$
\partial_n f = \frac{\partial g}{\partial x^n}(\phi(p))
$$
where $ g $ is a smooth extension of $ f\circ \phi^{-1} $ in a neighborhood of $ \phi(p) $ such that $ g\equiv f\circ \phi^{-1} $ where both are defined.
Now, one can show that each $ \partial_1,\dots,\partial_{n - 1} $ can be written as $ \partial_\mu = \dot\gamma(0) $ for some curve $ \gamma\colon \left]-\epsilon,\epsilon\right[\to M $ such that $ \gamma(0) = p $.
How can I show that this is not the case for $ \partial_n $? I.e., how can I show that here can't be any smooth curve $ \gamma\colon \left]-\epsilon,\epsilon\right[\to M $ such that $ \gamma(0) = p $ and $ \dot\gamma(0) = \partial_n $?

This is basic calculus: there is no $C^1$ function $f:I\to \Bbb{R}$, where $I\subset\Bbb{R}$ is an open interval containing the origin, such that $f(0)=0$ and $f’(0)>0$ and $f$ is non-negative. If there was, then by continuity of $f’$, there would be a neighbourhood $(-\delta,\delta)$ of the origin in $I$ on which $f’$ is strictly positive, hence $f$ would be strictly increasing there and thus $f<f(0)=0$ on $(-\delta,0)$.
Now apply this non-existence result to $f=x^n\circ \gamma$ to show no such $\gamma$ can exist.
